# A sample for jQuery based WYSIWYG Editor demonstrate OOP javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, rtf, fckeditor

Want a WYSIWYG jQuery Editor as an example to illustrate how to use jQuery to built OOP javascript component.

P.S.
It is so good stackoverflow can use markdown... Would be a heaven if users would love such thing too

Comment: Think about what you're asking and read it again before hitting "Submit."

Comment: sorry about the language, I try to rewrite it

Comment: you're asking for a wysiwyg editor for jQuery? Or a wysiwyg editor built on jQuery? I assume the latter, but I agree with cazlab, you should consider phrasing things better in the future.

Also (I'm not to be a dick, but...) the post-script is totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

[jHtmlArea - WYSIWYG HTML Editor for jQuery](https://web.archive.org/web/20180126074854/http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com:80/)

A simple, light weight, extensible WYSIWYG HTML Editor built on top of jQuery. This component allows you to easily display a WYSIWYG HTML Editor in place of any TextArea DOM Elements on the page. The minified script alone is 7kb, and with css and image files it's a total of 15kb.

This project also include Visual Studio JavaScript Intellisense support.

[image]
<sub>(source: [codeplex.com](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=jhtmlarea&DownloadId=76574))</sub>

Comment: This is perfect for a project I'm working on where I want to limit the amount of styling the user can apply (strike-through, colour and underline are often problematic). I love how easy the toolbar seems to be to define.

Answer (score 2):

http://projects.bundleweb.com.ar/jWYSIWYG/ looks outdated, better try this link to [jwysiwyg](http://code.google.com/p/jwysiwyg/)

Comment: That project on Google Code is buggy.

Answer (score 1):

jwysiwyg looks good but there's no useful documentation at all!

Answer (score 1):

Check CleEditor http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/

CLEditor supports the following browsers on both the mac and pc: IE 6.0+, FF 1.5+, Safari 4+, Chrome 5+ and Opera 10+. All testing is done using jQuery 1.4.2.

CLEditor provides a rich plugin development environment, allowing you to customize its user interface and functionality to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

http://wmd-editor.com/features#compatibility

or maybe if you just have time to write/modify for your own parse (as i will do)
use this:

http://markitup.jaysalvat.com

Answer (score 0):

The WYSIWYG which can accept formatted text copied from Microsoft Word, are...

- CLEditor
- jHTML Area
- NicEdit
- Xinha
- jWYSIWYG

I chose CLEdit, because the code is clean, and it allows me to decide how I want images to be aligned, and it doesn't have bugs like NicEdit. On NicEdit, it produces DOUBLE line breaks when HTML code is copied from other sites into the editor.